# How to simulate key presses or a click with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a Google Chrome extension and the site that I want to use my extension on requires me to click or tab onto a text box (because I think it runs javaScript verification "onClick" only). I can get the text in the box with my extension using:

```
document.getElementById("input1").value = 'test';
```

But when I click submit, it thinks I did not enter anything in the "input1" text box because I never clicked it or tabbed on it.

Can someone help me get around this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### Simulating a mouse click

My guess is that the webpage is listening to mousedown rather than click (which is bad for accessibility because when a user uses the keyboard, only focus and click are fired, not mousedown). So you should simulate mousedown, click, and mouseup (which, by the way, is [what the iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad do on tap events](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/08/iphone_events.html)).

To simulate the mouse events, you can use this snippet for browsers that support [DOM 2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent). For a more foolproof simulation, fill in the mouse position using `initMouseEvent` instead.

```
// DOM 2 Events
var dispatchMouseEvent = function(target, var_args) {
  var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  // If you need clientX, clientY, etc., you can call
  // initMouseEvent instead of initEvent
  e.initEvent.apply(e, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  target.dispatchEvent(e);
};
dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mouseover', true, true);
dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mousedown', true, true);
dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'click', true, true);
dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mouseup', true, true);
```

When you fire a simulated click event, the browser will actually fire the default action (e.g. navigate to the link's href, or submit a form).

In IE, the equivalent snippet is this (unverified since I don't have IE). I don't think you can give the event handler mouse positions.

```
// IE 5.5+
element.fireEvent("onmouseover");
element.fireEvent("onmousedown");
element.fireEvent("onclick");  // or element.click()
element.fireEvent("onmouseup");
```

### Simulating keydown and keypress

You can simulate keydown and keypress events, but unfortunately in Chrome they only fire the event handlers and don't perform any of the default actions. I think this is because the DOM 3 Events working draft describes this funky [order of key events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboard-event-order):

1. keydown (often has default action such as fire click, submit, or textInput events)
2. keypress (if the key isn't just a modifier key like Shift or Ctrl)
3. (keydown, keypress) with repeat=true if the user holds down the button
4. **default actions of keydown!!**
5. keyup

This means that you have to (while combing the [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html) and [DOM 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-textInput) drafts) simulate a large amount of what the browser would otherwise do. I hate it when I have to do that. For example, this is roughly how to simulate a key press on an input or textarea.

```
// DOM 3 Events
var dispatchKeyboardEvent = function(target, initKeyboradEvent_args) {
  var e = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvents");
  e.initKeyboardEvent.apply(e, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  target.dispatchEvent(e);
};
var dispatchTextEvent = function(target, initTextEvent_args) {
  var e = document.createEvent("TextEvent");
  e.initTextEvent.apply(e, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  target.dispatchEvent(e);
};
var dispatchSimpleEvent = function(target, type, canBubble, cancelable) {
  var e = document.createEvent("Event");
  e.initEvent.apply(e, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  target.dispatchEvent(e);
};

var canceled = !dispatchKeyboardEvent(element,
    'keydown', true, true,  // type, bubbles, cancelable
    null,  // window
    'h',  // key
    0, // location: 0=standard, 1=left, 2=right, 3=numpad, 4=mobile, 5=joystick
    '');  // space-sparated Shift, Control, Alt, etc.
dispatchKeyboardEvent(
    element, 'keypress', true, true, null, 'h', 0, '');
if (!canceled) {
  if (dispatchTextEvent(element, 'textInput', true, true, null, 'h', 0)) {
    element.value += 'h';
    dispatchSimpleEvent(element, 'input', false, false);
    // not supported in Chrome yet
    // if (element.form) element.form.dispatchFormInput();
    dispatchSimpleEvent(element, 'change', false, false);
    // not supported in Chrome yet
    // if (element.form) element.form.dispatchFormChange();
  }
}
dispatchKeyboardEvent(
    element, 'keyup', true, true, null, 'h', 0, '');
```

I don't think it is possible to simulate key events in IE.

Comment: In case anyone bumps into this looking for a **framework agnostic** way to fire any HTML and Mouse event (and set some options, if needed), have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript/6158050#6158050

Comment: @TweeZz, To be clear, I also did not rely on any libraries. But I do like the way you combined it all into one function.

Comment: :) Personally (if possible) I prefer an answer that I can just paste in my code to try it out :)

Comment: I have tried it (in Chrome Extension) and does not working... log from created Event show up that "which", "charCode" and "keyCode" are 0 instead of proper character/key code. Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @hamczu has someone already solved this?

Comment: @hamczu This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key/10520017#10520017) has a workaround for charCode = 0 issue. It is a [known bug in webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735) - has been open for around 5 years!

Comment: @TweeZz looks like your framework agnostic method doesn't provide a way to do key events as this answer does, yes?

Comment: @Michael Yea, it does NOT support key events.

Comment: In Firefox, the document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents') call gives me an "Operation is not supported" exception in Firefox; furthermore the Mozilla documentation says that this method is deprecated in favor of event constructors...  Looks like it should be "KeyboardEvent" (singular).

Comment: The initKeyBoardEvent function is not found in the latest Firefox.  There is initKeyEvent ("Gecko specific"?) but that function doesn't take the same number of parameters.

Comment: Any solution for dispatching keyboard events in a Chrome Extension?

Comment: This code does not work anymore in the newest version of chrome as of 2016-09-17

Comment: This code does not work anymore in the newest version of chrome as of 2017-01-08, this answer needs update!

Answer (score 8):

you can raise the click event on an element by doing

```
// this must be done after input1 exists in the DOM
var element = document.getElementById("input1");

if (element) element.click();
```

**[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/Nz7ab/)**

Comment: I tried this but for some reason the the site still thinks I am not typing anything in... weird.

Comment: try other events like `focus`, `change`, `keypress`

Comment: I'm finding that this doesn't work on Chrome (WebKit).  The click property of the HTMLAnchorElement is undefined.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you running and on what platform? I just tried visiting the example page on 15.0.874.102 on Windows7 and it's working as expected. Does the example work for you?

Comment: element.click is not a function

Answer (score 7):

Or even shorter, with only standard modern Javascript:

```
var first_link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
first_link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

The `new MouseEvent` constructor takes a required event type name, then an optional object (at least in Chrome). So you could, for example, set some properties of the event:

```
first_link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true}));
```

Answer (score 5):

For simulating keyboard events in Chrome:

There is a related bug in webkit that keyboard events when initialized with 
initKeyboardEvent get an incorrect keyCode and charCode of 0: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735

A working solution for it is posted in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520017/1328825).

Answer (score 0):

Focus might be what your looking for. With tabbing or clicking I think u mean giving the element the focus. Same code as Russ (Sorry i stole it :P) but firing an other event.

```
// this must be done after input1 exists in the DOM
var element = document.getElementById("input1");

if (element) element.focus();
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this also, along with the click, but the site still thinks I am not typing anything in....