# simulating mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to simulate key presses or a click with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript)

I know it's an old and repeated question, but before replying "google it", read the question plz .

I'm trying to simulate some of user interactions with page in my chrome extension and one of them is mouse click. I can "click" on links with a proper href and move to that page (window.location etc ) but my problem is with anchors that load content via ajax, for example in facebook home page, if I want to trigger the "Top News" news feed button, in theory I should use : `$(".uiHeaderActions .fwn").click();` but it doesnt do anything ... and idea ?

Comment: If there is no typo or issue elsewhere in your code, calling the click() event should work.

Comment: lol, I've tested every possible way, not working :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe they hook in to a different event than click?

Check out this duplicate ticket: [Is there a way to simulate key presses or a click with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript)

Comment: I'm gonna try it with facebook one, but I had the same problem with google n other sites as well, I'll see if that function works

Comment: I'm going to try it too. Just wondering... are you writing a test automation extension or something? That'd be pretty cool.

Comment: it sorta works, I just need to modify my extension a little bit, but worked on google, so thanks ! the extension is something cool, you can record your interactions on page and later pass it to someone else to for example show them how to do something on a site, for example if u wanna teach ur friend how to use facebook chat ... and its gonna be open source ;) version beta will be out soon :)

Comment: @hakim-sina if you haven't seen Selenium, check it out.  It sounds like what you are describing (for firefox).

Answer (score -1):

Can you be more specific ? This is how I think

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('.uiHeaderActions fwn').click(function(){
       $(this).load('something.com');
```

});
});

Good luck

Comment: Oo .... errm, I just want to simulate physical mouse click on an element ... and yes, I have tried .click as I said in my question, but it doesnt work ...