# Google Chrome Extensions - Set focus to omnibar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I´m developing a Google Chrome Extension which need to set the focus to the Omnibar. I haven´t found anything in the API reference. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My 'hack' would perhaps be creating a new tab page as the focus will be set to the omnibar. But I don't know how to sustain the focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such API method, plus looks like it is not possible to simulate a keyboard shortcut that puts focus into the ominbox (CTRL+L) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript/4176116#4176116).