# Chrome Extension Send Key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to simulate a key press from a chrome extension? For example when I click the extension button I can specify that keys 'ABC' be sent to browser window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately no (it is a javascript problem, Chrome API doesn't provide any help).

All you can do is dispatch a keypress event (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events) for example), but you can't emulate actual button press. If parent page listens to keypress events, then it will catch it (this event won't have all the info as a real button press event, so it might still not work), otherwise nothing would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you have to read the HTML5 spec and simulate everything that the browser would do. [Here was my last attempt at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript/4176116#4176116).