# check HTML form checkbox but ensure that listeners get called

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trigger onchange event manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/trigger-onchange-event-manually)

I have a checkbox in a form that I want to set to checked. That's easy:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("mycheckbox");
checkbox.checked = true;
```

But I want to do this so that the onChange listeners get called. How do I do this?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/trigger-onchange-event-manually) a duplicate?

Comment: Evidently yes. I figured there was, but I couldn't find one. Thanks!

Comment: Better answer is actually for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript