# Simulating a mouse click at (x, y) on an HTML5 canvas element

Tags: javascript, events, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I've been attempting to programmatically simulate a mouse click at arbitrary coordinates on a canvas element. Because of technology constraints, I need to avoid jQuery which would make this easier.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053642/2682870) answer, I am able to get coordinates of manual clicks.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18365452/2682870) answer, I'm able to programmatically simulate a mouse click. But unfortunately I need to de-jQuery-ify it, which is, I think, where I've run into problems.

If I try to do something like:

```
document.querySelector("canvas").dispatchEvent(new Event("mousedown", {pageX: 1, pageY: 1}));
```

or

```
document.querySelector("canvas").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown", {pageX: 1, pageY: 1}));
```

or combinations of the above using 'click' instead of 'mousedown'

I still get strange 'undefined' errors that I don't understand (other than that I can see they are referring to 'mousedown') and never successfully simulate the click.

**Some working (and not working) examples:**

Working: [Displays coordinates of clicks](http://jsfiddle.net/98wbyrLp/)

Working: [Fires a programmatic click](http://jsfiddle.net/u8zpo9tb/)

Not Working: [Combining the two above](https://jsfiddle.net/wpmj79gu/)

Not Working: [Trying to fire a programmatic click without jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/8xnpryzm/)

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer if you just say you get an `undefined` error. Can you post a working sample of your code which clearly shows the issue?

Comment: Sure, I've added four working examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your jQuery approach is that you are mixing it with a plain JavaScript event listener. This does not work with jQuery.

If you want to trigger an event and listen it using jQuery you have to use it's `.trigger()` and `.mousedown()` methods.

Here's an example:

```js
function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
  let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  document.getElementById('output').innerText = x + ", " + y;
}

canvasElem = document.querySelector("canvas");

$('#canvas_element').mousedown(function(e) {
  getMousePosition(canvasElem, e);
});

var e = jQuery.Event("mousedown", {
  clientX: 50,
  clientY: 50
});
$('#canvas_element').trigger(e);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas_element"></canvas>
<div id="output"></div>
```

All of the above can be done using just JavaScript too of course.

```js
function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
  let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  document.getElementById('output').innerText = x + ", " + y;
}

canvasElem = document.querySelector("canvas");

canvasElem.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  getMousePosition(canvasElem, e);
});

canvasElem.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
  clientX: 50,
  clientY: 50
}));
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas_element"></canvas>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So my js approach was literally only not working because I was using pageX and not clientX? None of the answers or posts/blogs/articles I'd read anywhere specified anything about that... is there any documentation anywhere that makes this stuff understandable without this level of headache?

Comment: No problem David - glad I could help! The different position properties a mouse event returns are indeed a bit confusing. There's a nifty summary over here: [https://www.codetd.com/en/article/12514516](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/12514516)

Comment: That's an excellent resource, bookmarked