# Selenium Webdriver mousedown command

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am writing tests for a Java application which has been developed using the Vaadin framework. For the tests I am using **Robot Framework**. At some steps I have to use robot framework commands like **execute javascript**.

For example, for finding a component I have to execute the following command:

```
execute javascript    document.getElementById('button-create').click()
```

Which works without any problem. Primitives like `Click Element` are not working because Vaadin doesn't wait until the whole page is loaded and therefore some ids are not yet assigned at run time.

Unfortunately this application has been developed in such a way that some components are not reacting to the event `click` but to the event `mousedown`. That is, at the Java console of chrome I can perform the following command:

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('table-cell-wrapper')[1].mousedown();
```

and the action is performed without any problem. So far so good.

Unfortunately when trying to do the same at robot framework

```
    execute javascript    document.getElementsByClassName('table-cell-wrapper')[1].mousedown();
```

I am getting te following error:

```
Executing JavaScript:
document.getElementsByClassName('table-cell-wrapper')[1].mousedown();
20131029 12:22:12.445 :  INFO : </td></tr><tr><td colspan="3"><a href="selenium-    screenshot-1.png"><img src="selenium-screenshot-1.png" width="800px"></a>20131029 12:22:12.453 :  FAIL : 
WebDriverException: Message: u'document.getElementsByClassName(...)[1].mousedown is not a function' ;
```

Then the question is... how can I trigger the event `mousedown` on a given element using Javascript and Webdriver.

My environment is:

```
RIDE 1.2.1 running on Python 2.7.5. 
Robot Framework 2.8.1
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           Screenshot
Library           Dialogs
Library           Collections
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to use Robots?  What's wrong with standard Selenium commands, or the javascript commands you were using?

Comment: As I said the application is written using Vaadin. This framework doesn't wait until the complete page is loaded. Therefore at running time id are not yet assigned and you cannot find the elements for clicking (or mousedown).

Answer (score 0):

From Selenium2Library [Execute Javascript](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript) keyword:

> Note that, by default, the code will be executed in the context of the
>   Selenium object itself, so this will refer to the Selenium object. Use
>   window to refer to the window of your application, e.g.
>   window.document.getElementById('foo')

So you might want to put `window.` in there.

`mousedown()` is not a pure Javascript function. JQuery does have one and there is a event called `mousedown` in plain JS also.

If some element does not exists after the page is loaded causing

```
Click Element    foobar
```

to fail, you can use [Wait Until Page Contains Element](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20Until%20Page%20Contains%20Element) and then click that element. You could write your own Press Element keyword to make it more usefull:

```
Press Element    ${locator}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${locator}
    Click Element    ${locator}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no, the problem is not the "window" reference. I've already put some "wait until page contains" and this is not solving the problem. I have to perform a "mouse down" at an element and I don't know how.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that simulating mousedown through execute javascript will not make any difference compared to my press element approach but here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript. And if JQuery is in use window.$('.wrapper').mousedown() will do.