# Set event properties while triggering built in events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, jqlite

How to pass event properties while triggering built in JavaScript events?

For: `el.triggerHandler('mousedown');` how do I pass set event.which that is accessed inside the function?

Comment: More specifically, I am running this inside a jasmine unit test case. Using `triggerHandler()` from AngularJS jqLite.

Comment: The jqLite documentations sez that [jqLite.on does not support the `selector` or `eventData` parameters](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/jqLite/onargs).

Comment: Does that mean jQuery is necessary to perform visual interaction tests ?

Comment: You could use plain old javascript to [simulate a mousedown event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4176116/2119660), which should trigger the proper handlers for mousedown