# javascript - how to simply simulate as if user pressed Enter Key (without Jquery / awtRobot etc...)

Tags: javascript, keypress, enter

**Need to simulate as if user pressed Enter Key on keyboard, but using some simple solution and not requiring Jquery or awtRobot or similar.**

**More Details If Necessary** : 
(1) A multi-field window rendered by legacy software, is rendered on a windows OS desktop. Button click on the window calls Javascript code. 
(2) Upon some processing in Javascript, the Javascript updates back a field on this window. The updated value is presented in the field but it is not actually updated within the window internals, only presented, until Enter Key is pressed.
(3) In order to refrain from asking the user to explicitly press Enter, arises the need to simulate the Enter Key Press.

Comment: Looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript) maybe?